# Change ToolbarItem Text/Icon parameters

Tags: user-interface, toolbar, maui

I am new to MAUI. And I haven't done anything complex with Xamarin as well.

The application I am testing with, has Shell navigation. And I can't find a way to change the toolbar items.

I would like to be able to change either the FontSize of the text, or the color of the SVG image. And I do not want those changes to affect the rest of my application, if possible. But if there is no other way, I can live with it.

I have managed to add styling to buttons, Labels etc... If styling is an option to this, it will be even better.

If I am on the wrong path, if you point me out why, I will be also grateful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just change a part of pages in your project. You can try to use a `<Shell.TitleView>` instead of the `<Shell.ToolBarItem>` in the content pages you want. Such as:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiAppTest.MainPage">
<Shell.TitleView>
    <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="End">
        <Label Text="hello" TextColor="Red" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        <Image Source="your image" Margin="10" Background="green"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Comment: I've tried this, before I posted this question, and I did not like it. Mostly because for just changing few parameters, I have to use it in each page. Maybe I will add some base class or something and work from there. No one seems to be suggesting anything better...

Comment: I also tried to find a way to custom the renderer of the toolbaritem in the maui, but I failed. So I provide this solution. I think it's easier than using a handler to custom the renderer. @H.A.H.

Answer (score 0):

You can change style of TabBar in `Style.xaml` in path `\Resources\Style\`. Search in file for `Shell.TabBarForegroundColor`. You will get `TargetType="Shell"` and this is style for `AppShell.xaml`.

Comment: I've already went through most of that. The TabBar parameters, seem to be affecting the tabbar on the bottom. Am I missing something?